# Format Double to fixed Width C#

Tags: c#, formatting, format

My requirements are as follows:

I have a double number. It can be positive as well as negative. I want to use String.Format() to format it.

The Output Number(positive(no sign)/negative(including sign)/zero) should be fixed width: 11
All numbers should have 2 places of decimal.

Examples:

```
1.2     00000001.20
.2      00000000.20
-.2     -0000000.20
12      00000012.00
0       00000000.00
-0      00000000.00
12.555  00000012.55
```

Basically, what I want is fixed width(11 digits). 2 Decimal points. No positive sign. Negative sign included in fixed width.

What I have tried:

```
{0:00000000.00;0:0000000.00;0:00000000.00}
```

Please  tell me what is the right way to do this.

Comment: Should simply be `{0:00000000.00;-0000000.00}`

Comment: Thanks!!! I forgot I could simply use a - to format the negative. But if I do not format the negative sign, shouldn't it output as it is? I mean 0.0000000.00 should give a negative of width 11 including the sign.

Comment: No, the "width" includes your - sign, so if its a positive number its 10 digits + 1 decimal, if its negative its 9 digits, 1 decimal, and 1 negative sign. In your example, the negative sign occupies one of the digit positions which means you need different format strings.

Comment: @Madeyedexter No, if you specify a "negative" format you have to include the negative sign if you want it in the output.  This lets you do "clever" thinks by reversing the sign just in the output format: `{-0.0000,0.0000}`.

Comment: @DStanley so if I don't put the - in the section formatting of negatives, the - will be stripped and replaced with a zero?

Comment: No there will not be a character there.  It will output using the format you specify (with or without the negative sign)

Comment: @RonBeyer `{0:00000000.00;0:0000000.00;0:00000000.00}` (-ve section has only 10 digits) should work, right?

Comment: @Madeyedexter No, first you have `0:` in there on each format, it should only appear once at the beginning. You also don't have a negative sign specified for the negative section, so it will look like a positive number with a field width one smaller (if you don't specify it, it doesn't add it). Last, the zero section is fine, but really not needed, it will use the positive section (don't want to get into theory on +/- 0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use section modifiers to give the output you need:

```
string format = "{0:00000000.00;-0000000.00}";

Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format, 1.2));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format, .2));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format, -.2));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format, 12.0));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format, -0.0));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format, 12.555));
```

Prints out:

```
00000001.20
00000000.20
-0000000.20
00000012.00
00000000.00
00000012.56
```

It's basically `{position:postive format;negative format;zero format}`

**Note**: position is only used for formatted strings, you can also use it with `double.ToString(string)` without the "position" element;
If zero format is not provided, format for positive format section is used to format Zero.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx for more detail about the `;` section format.

Comment: I was aware of the section formatting. I have already mentioned it in my question. My main problem was formatting the numbers as fixed width. Thanks for the answer Ron!

Comment: I try to be thorough not just for you but for anybody who comes across this question later, so explaining it wasn't necessarily aimed at you just as a general "how-to" for others. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Format("{0:00000000.00}", 1.2)
```

works fine for me

Comment: Try it with a negative number, you get 11 digits + the - sign, he would need 10 digits and the - sign.

Comment: you may use if (value < 0) .. else .. Not a good way but works.

Answer (score 0):

```
double d = -12.365;
string s = d.ToString("0:00000000.00");   //-0:00000012.37
string sOut = d.ToString("00000000.00");  //-00000012.37
```

Comment: I think you are way off on the number of digits on the left/right of the decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a second format section for negative numbers. Declaring it as a `Func` or extension method might be helpful if you need to reuse it. Like so:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<double, string> toFixedWidth = (d) => { 
                return string.Format("{0:00000000.00;-0000000.00}", d); 
            };

            foreach (var d in new double[] { 1.2, 0.2, -0.2, 12, 0, -0, 12.555 })
            {
                Console.WriteLine(toFixedWidth(d));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
00000001,20
00000000,20
-0000000,20
00000012,00
00000000,00
00000000,00
00000012,56
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I'd say it all depends on the intended usage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general function for this.  It works the same as the other answers, but it builds the formatting string dynamically based on the `length` (total length) and `decimals` parameters.

```
public static string FormatDoubleAsFixedLengthString(double value, int length, int decimals)
{
    int wholeDigits = length - decimals;

    // Provide a spot for the negative sign if present.
    if (value < 0)
    {
        wholeDigits--;
    }

    string wholeDigitsFormat = new String('0', wholeDigits);
    string decimalDigitsFormat = new String('0', decimals);
    string format = $"{{0:{wholeDigitsFormat}.{decimalDigitsFormat}}}";
    return string.Format(format, value);
}
```

And while we're at it, here's the same function but for *integers*:

```
public static string FormatIntAsFixedLengthString(int value, int length)
{
    // Provide a spot for the negative sign if present.
    if (value < 0)
    {
        length--;
    }
    return string.Format($"{{0:D{length}}}", value);
}
```